# Lower screen resolution while maintaining original pixel density

Tags: windows-7, viewport, screen-resolution

I'd like to play some older games on Windows 7. Running them isn't an issue, but the increase of monitor size and pixel density of later monitors is. Pre-rendered games intended to be played full-screen on e.g. a 640x480 resolution are now "blown up" to fit on a complete screen, making everything look unsharp. I've been looking at different solutions, but so far to no avail for a selection of games:

1. Running the game in "windowed mode" is an option for those games that support it.
2. [DxWnd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dxwnd/) could be used to force some games in "windowed mode", but it causes some applications to crash as well.
3. [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) works nicely since it will automatically resize to the applications desired full-screen resolution, but this is no option if VirtualBox's 3D support is insufficient to play the game.
4. Drivers like those of AMD or NVIDIA provide means to force maintaining pixel aspect ratio if pixel aspect ratio is an issue on wide-screen monitors

All of the above don't work for me for one game, since it does not provide "windowed mode", DxWnd makes it crash, VirtualBox's 3D support is insufficient and aspect ratio isn't an issue on my monitor.

Which brings me to the question: is there a way to lower the screen resolution while maintaining original pixel density of the monitor instead of having it fill up the whole screen? Thus essentially creating a smaller view port for the Windows environment to use and filling up the rest of the screen with big black borders?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the game and click property's and then try ticking this option.
.[image]

Comment: Tried that, it will still cause the complete 640x480 pixels to be spread across the complete screen.

Comment: Don't know then this is how I do it.